# How to find total number of HTTP processes in a specific IP by using php?

Tags: php, http, command, ip

using [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function, i can execute an external program.

I got the total number of HTTP process by using following code.

```
$count = exec("ps -ef | grep http | wc -l");
```

And now , this is my question. How can I get the total number of HTTP process from a specific IP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are on a linux system. You can retrieve socket statistics through the `ss` utility. E.g. in order to list all connections to your http or https port, you can use:

```
ss -t '( sport = :http or sport = :https )'
```

You can further filter this by IP. So let's say you want to filter all connections by the remote address 1.2.3.4:

```
ss -t '( sport = :http or sport = :https )' dst 1.2.3.4
```

Now mapping connections to actual processes is a bit tricky as traditionally, one connection has been handled by one process each. But this isn't always the case. You can let `ss` display the listening programs with the `p` switch like so:

```
ss -tp '( sport = :http or sport = :https )' dst 1.2.3.4
```

You will find that `ss` is listing those conveniently in one line, so we can grep these out and count the uniques:

```
ss -tp '( sport = :http or sport = :https )' dst 1.2.3.4 | grep users | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

Putting this together:

```
$count = exec(sprintf(
    'ss -tp "( sport = :http or sport = :https )" dst %s | grep users | sort | uniq | wc -l',
    escapeshellarg($remoteAddress)
));
```

Comment: thank you for answering, But it is showing zero. the is count always zero.

Comment: Sorry, missed the `p` param in the last two examples.

Comment: Hm, that's odd. Can you enter the result into a shell and tell me what it gives?

Comment: Yes, I did it. it is still showing zero. I have tested with two IP's . But result is **0**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108392/discussion-between-dasourcerer-and-yahoo).